# compare two values in jquery i cannot get "Hi" alert

Tags: jquery

how i can compare two values json return true in is delivered property and i want to compare it with string

```
$.getJSON('/SalesInvoice/GetSI/' + $('#SearchSI').val(), function (data) {

     if (data.ex == "OK") {
         if(data.Voucher.IsDelivered == "true")
         {

             alert('hi');
         };
}
```

Comment: Uh, so the comparison failed, maybe you should log the values and figure out what they are then ?

Comment: What's data? What does GetSI do? this does not contain the bear minimum of information to answer this question

Comment: Also see [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Answer (score 0):

If in the JSON, the value is `true` and you want to check it using `"true"` it would result in false.

I think you should convert the string to a simple bool true.

```
if(data.Voucher.IsDelivered == true)
{
   alert('hi');
};
```

Or a simpler one

```
if(data.Voucher.IsDelivered)
{
   alert('hi');
};
```

Because if you see, the `(bool == string) = false`. Always check the data types while using a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add an else to the IF statement so that you can see exactly what is in the variable in question. Like this:

```
 if (data.ex == "OK") {
     if(data.Voucher.IsDelivered == "true")
     {

         alert('hi');
     } else {
         alert( data.Voucher.IsDelivered + ' = ' + typeof data.Voucher.IsDelivered )
     }
```

Comment: this is similar to @adeneos comment, how does this help?